# Custom ListBox control does not allow scrolling

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

I am build a Logger control on top of ListBox and i am having difficulty getting the Logger to work (i.e. the ListBox scrolling). Here is the code i am using:

Style definition in Resource dictionary:

```
<Style TargetType="local:Logger">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Head}" Margin="4"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Body}" Margin="4" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

C# counterpart where Logger is defined:

```
public class LoggerMessage
{
    public string Head { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}

public class Logger : ListBox
{
    private ObservableCollection<LoggerMessage> _log;

    public Logger() : base()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(Logger);
        _log = new ObservableCollection<LoggerMessage>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            _log.Add(new LoggerMessage() { Head = "Msg: " + i, Body = "Some really long text which hopefully wraps around." });
        }
        this.ItemsSource = _log;
    }

    public void log(LoggerMessage item)
    {
        _log.Add(item);
    }
}
```

After a bit of researching and trial and error, i came up with style template (see below) that solves the problem but, i am not able to grasp why it did not work in version 1. Why do i have to explicitly "redefine" the ScrollViewer in the ControlTemplate

```
<Style TargetType="local:Logger">
    <!-- Begin - Redef of ControlTemplate -->
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:Logger">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                     <ItemsPresenter/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <!-- End - Redef of ControlTemplate -->
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Head}" Margin="4"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Body}" Margin="4" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Thanks in advance for anykind of explanation.

Kind Regards

Comment: FYI, I just ran into the same problem. It appears as though just removing the setting for DefaultStyleKey seems to fix it. I don't think I've had any negative side effects yet. Is it possible this isn't necessary anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of digging in the MSDN documentation ([DefaultStyleKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.defaultstylekey%28VS.95%29.aspx)), it appears the applying the style to the control is a complete overwrite. It seems that the style of the base class is not inherited as i was assuming. The document does not tell it explicitly but, the above experiment sort lead to this understanding.